# Placing more than one sentence inside parentheses

Tags: пунктуация

In case if I place more than one sentence inside parentheses, where do I need to place the last period? Before the closing parenthesis or right after it? Or do I need a period there at all?

Which one of the three options here is correct?

**A:**

Джек никогда не обращал на такие вещи никакого внимания. (Многие в нашем городке имели точно такое же отношение ко всему происxодящему, как и Джек. Это было своего рода признаком смелости и даже силы, когда кто-нибудь не проявлял никакого интереса и не придавал никакого значения мистическим силам, присутствовавшим в этиx местаx и время от время дающим о себе знать**.)**

**B:**

Джек никогда не обращал на такие вещи никакого внимания. (Многие в нашем городке имели точно такое же отношение ко всему происxодящему, как и Джек. Это было своего рода признаком смелости и даже силы, когда кто-нибудь не проявлял никакого интереса и не придавал никакого значения мистическим силам, присутствовавшим в этиx местаx и время от время дающим о себе знать**).**

**C:**

Джек никогда не обращал на такие вещи никакого внимания. (Многие в нашем городке имели точно такое же отношение ко всему происxодящему, как и Джек. Это было своего рода признаком смелости и даже силы, когда кто-нибудь не проявлял никакого интереса и не придавал никакого значения мистическим силам, присутствовавшим в этиx местаx и время от время дающим о себе знать**)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only **A** is acceptable.

According to [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=oszp)

> **§ 202.** Точка, знаки вопросительный и восклицательный и многоточие
>   ставятся **перед закрывающей скобкой, если относятся только к словам,
>   заключенным в скобки**, но после закрывающей скобки, если относятся ко
>   всему предложению вместе со словами, заключенными в скобки, например:
>
> > ...Вы не изволите знать здешнего судью – Мылова Павла Лукича?.. Не
> >     знаете... Ну, все равно. (Он откашлялся и протер глаза.) 
> >     *Тургенев*
> >
> > Он знал латинский язык, и виргилиевское «quos ego!» (я вас!) не было
> >     ему чуждым. *Тургенев*
>
> **Но:**
>
> > Обед был действительно недурен и в качестве
> >     воскресного не обошелся без трепещущего желе и испанских ветров
> >     (пирожного). *Тургенев*
> >
> > И разве я не вижу, что этот дурень смотрит только на Бурьенку (надо ее
> >     прогнать)! *Л. Толстой*
>
> **Примечание.** После цитаты, за которой в скобках
>   следует ссылка на автора и на источник, точка опускается и ставится
>   после ссылки вне скобки, например:
>
> > Вспомнились слова Базарова:
> >     «Природа не храм, а мастерская, а человек в ней работник» (Тургенев).
>
> **§ 203.** После закрывающей скобки, которой заканчивается предложение,
>   ставится знак препинания, требуемый предложением в целом, независимо
>   от того, какой знак может стоять перед закрывающей скобкой, например:
>
> > Единственный сын его, дед мой Лев Александрович, во время мятежа 1762
> >     года остался верен Петру III, не хотел присягнуть Екатерине – и был
> >     посажен в крепость вместе с Измайловым (странна судьба и союз сих
> >     имен!). *Пушкин*

So, your sample is really close to the first quote by Turgenev. Period here applies to the sentence inside parentheses.
Both **B** and **C** are incorrect because sentence inside the brackets is not finished with appropriate punctuation mark.

There is only one case when you need to put a period after parenthesis: when parenthesized text is a last part of a sentence (Check out the last example by Pushkin in the quote above.).